# Is it possible to avoid a TRichEdit losing its focus when clicking a button (e.g. Bold)?

Tags: delphi, controls, focus, trichedit

Using delphi and rich edit, I need to replicate something along the lines of this very editor I'm writing in, when you select a text and press on the Bold button, the text remains selected instead of unselecting and losing focus.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the editor control to lose focus when making the selection bold? That sounds like a highly annoying bug!

Comment: Could you please re-state what you said? I cannot understand, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, now I think I see the issue. You have a `TRichEdit` and a `TButton`. Then you do something like

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with RichEdit1.SelAttributes do
    Style := Style + [fsBold];
end;
```

and you are annoyed by the fact that the Rich Edit control loses its focus when you click `Button1`. Normally you use a `TToolButton` in a `TToolbar` as the 'bold' button. This will not make the editor lose its focus, because a `TToolButton` is not a windowed control.

If you do not wish to use a `TToolBar` (or any equivalent control), simply use a `TSpeedButton` instead of a `TButton`.

The normal way of doing this, however, is to use a `TActionList`. Drop such a control on your form, and then add a new action, call it `ActnBold` or something. Set the caption to `'Bold'`, the hint to `'Make the selection bold.'`, add the shortcut `Ctrl+B`, and write

```
with RichEdit1.SelAttributes do
  Style := Style + [fsBold];
```

in its `OnExecute` event. Then you can *associate* this action to any button, speed button, toolbar button, menu item, ..., simply by setting the control's `Action` property to `ActnBold`.

If you really, really want to use a windowed control, such as a `TButton`, then you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with RichEdit1.SelAttributes do
    Style := Style + [fsBold];
  RichEdit1.SetFocus;
end;
```

but it isn't beautiful (IMHO).

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!! Um, actually I'm using SpeedButton mode from cxButton (devexpress control). I'll see if I can make it work, otherwise I'll focus on the tool bar. Thanks.

Comment: One other option is to set `HideSelection` to false.

Comment: @Sertac: No, that will make it worse. The user will now *think* that the editor has focus while it has not.

Comment: Is `cxButton` a windowed control (ie, `TWinControl` descendant)?  The standard `TSpeedButton` component is not (it is a `TGraphicControl` descendant instead).  Graphical control cannot receive or steal input focus.